# PayloadTooLargeError with Limit Set

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Hi I have a problem with Express.js, I need to send a base64 file to node.js, my configuraizone is what you see below, but when I send the file I get this error: PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large! I've read that you need to set the limit on body-parsers like I did below, the fact is that it keeps happening to me how can I solve this?

**Node Code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const myParser = require("body-parser");
//const http = require('http');
const app = express();

//app.use(myParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))
app.use(myParser.json());
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(myParser.json({limit: '200mb'}));
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({limit: '200mb', extended: true}));

//Porta predefinita Server
const RunPort = 8988;
//Avvio del server sulla porta specificata
app.listen(RunPort, function () {
    console.log("Serve run on Port: ", RunPort);
})
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In your code you have called twice to `bodyParser.json()` & `bodyParser.urlencoded()`, the problem is that the one with `limit` is after the call without options, which defaults to `100kb`.
So when you POST something greater than `100kb` that error will be thrown, since the first parser will not go to the next middleware.

You shouldn't call `bodyParser[method]` twice.

Remove:

```
app.use(myParser.json());
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

And leave:

```
app.use(myParser.json({limit: '200mb'}));
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({limit: '200mb', extended: true}));
```

Depending on how you're posting the `base64` string, you may want to use:

```
app.use(myParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));
```

Comment: for newer express app, we can make it like this:
app.use(express.json({ limit: '200mb' })

Comment: When I leave those limits, the request, having problem before, just not coming, it's being interrupted/stopped somehow I guess.

@Linc your suggestion has also same problem.

I mean my problematic end point is not triggered at all when using these.