# 413 payload too large, for base64 string after adjusting size in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried to make a post request, to my node server, with a base64 encoded file.

I get a  PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large exception, so i went to extend the payload limit, by Express 4 convention

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));
```

[image: Here is a console.log of the picture]

however the problem still occurs, can anybody help me on why?

here are my global variables

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: Can you share a pastebin link with the string?

Comment: It's to large for a pastebin

Comment: a couple of questions stand out, the base64 string is definitely under 100MB? and is the bodyParser limit case-sensitive? 100 mega**b**its would be significantly smaller than 100 mega**B**ytes

Comment: depending on the kind of error message you're getting, it might be another part of your stack:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917401/error-request-entity-too-large/40745569#40745569

Comment: Got exaclty the same problem. The payload limit works when you upload files. But not on large strings like this.

Comment: @Dedi are you using nginx?

Answer (score 5):

In your code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Should be not used without options. If no options, the default size I believe will be about 100 Kb.

You can pay attention to `text` parameter below:

```
app.use(myParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));
```

If you are using a last version of express, so it should be something like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));
```

Try adding also a flag `parameterLimit` > 100000 or larger.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have called twice to bodyParser.json() & bodyParser.urlencoded(), the problem is that the one with limit is after the calls without options, which defaults to 100kb. So when you POST something greater than 100kb that error will be thrown, since the first parser will not go to the next middleware.

- You shouldn't call **bodyParser[method]** twice.
- Depending on how you're posting the base64 string, you may want to use

  app.use(myParser.text({ limit: '200mb' }));

Answer (score 2):

It beacuse you called the same **bodyParser.[method]** twice. Never do that. Refer this question - [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988891/payloadtoolargeerror-with-limit-set)

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me set the 'type' in addition to the 'limit' for bodyparser

```
var app = express(); 
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024*10, type:'application/json'}); 
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true,limit:1024*1024*10,type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
app.use(jsonParser);
app.use(urlencodedParser);
```

Comment: Tried this. Did not work.